# Sms API for java web application?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, sms

I want to make a technology where x person sends a message to buy a ticket for his train and after that he gets his message "Your train ticket is booked successfully". In that case what SMS API should i use? And yes i'm making web application using java, jsp and servlet.

***Surely, Help would be appreciated!!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get an SMS provider for this.
They also provide you with an API for their own service, there is no free "out there" API for this.